# searchBarTextDidBeginEditing delegate method called again on back button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am developing iPhone app in which i  got stuck at one point.

I have one viewController with navigation bar hidden and search bar is in the centre of the page.

when user clicks on searchBar `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method gets fired.

after this on text change of searchBar `textDidChange` method i am loading live data in tableview and on click of tableview i am navigating to other page with navigation bar non hidden.

Now when i press back button again i comes to search page here `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` method again gets fired.

Why this method gets called again on back press ?

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `SearcBarTextDidBeginEditing` called due to your search display controller still in Active mode,

In your TableView Delegate Method,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];


   // Set Navigation
}
```

And In Same Class , In View Will Appear SET,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.searchDisplayController.Active = NO;

}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: If its helps you then you can Accept it as correct for reference of others.

Answer (score 1):

I think the UITextField keeps the focus on itself when you navigate.

Try `[textField resignFirstResponder]` when you click on your tableView to navigate.